# how do i embed text in a pdf i'm making with microsoft power point (2007 i think)

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint, fonts, embedded-fonts

need it to print right on a print shop's computer

which fonts do i need to embed? i found somewhere arial doesn't need to be embed, but it doesn't seem to be the default sans-serif on newer microsoft stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I use [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) to create PDFs and I always embed all fonts for convenience.

In the Options window, click Formats to expand the Formats panel. To embed fonts, click on the Fonts tab and check the "Embed all fonts" box and uncheck the "Subset fonts when percentage of used characters below" box.

[image]